# How to move individual apps & files from old to new macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an old 09 macbookpro running 10.8.6, & have just bought a refurbed mid-2012 one running 10.11.5. I want to transfer some of my old files & apps from old to new, but not all of them. I'm looking for a simple way to do this; I'm not a techie, just an end user.

Comment: Can you try the application preinsralled on your new Mac called Migration assistant?

Comment: Migration Assistant transfers everything.  I want to move files & apps selectively.

Comment: I've been told I don't want to use Migration Asst because I won't be able to move files & Apps selectively.

Comment: I strongly recommend you try it. Near the bottom of this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350 it shows you being able to choose which data gets copied.

Answer (score 1):

- Turn off the 10.8.6 computer.
- Connect it to the new computer with either a Firewire or Thunderbolt cable.
- Hold T down on the 10.8.6 computer.This will boot it into  [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725?locale=en_US)
- The 10.8.6 computer's disk should now be mounted on the new computer. You can transfer just the files that you want and then unmount the older computer.

Transferring the files with a USB flash drive would work as well.

Comment: OP probably doesn't have a firewire or thunderbolt cable, which is why I was going to say to use a flash drive, but you mentioned that for me. Good advice right here.